# Kafka broker shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In a single cluster/instance installation of **kafka/zookeeper v2.4.1** (binary *kafka_2.13-2.4.1.tgz*) in **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with Ubuntu 18.04**, the kafka broker shuts down unexpectedly during the cleanup of log files with the below error message:

```
ERROR Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-11 in dir /tmp/kafka-logs due to IOException (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$resize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:188)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.scala:17)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.resize(AbstractIndex.scala:174)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1(AbstractIndex.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.scala:17)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.trimToValidSize(AbstractIndex.scala:240)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.onBecomeInactiveSegment(LogSegment.scala:508)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.cleanSegments(LogCleaner.scala:595)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.$anonfun$doClean$6(LogCleaner.scala:530)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.$anonfun$doClean$6$adapted(LogCleaner.scala:529)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:305)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.doClean(LogCleaner.scala:529)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.clean(LogCleaner.scala:503)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanLog(LogCleaner.scala:372)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:345)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.tryCleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:325)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.doWork(LogCleaner.scala:314)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

The directory *__consumer_offsets-11* that fails to be cleaned up exists:

[Kafka logs dir contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o60uO.png)

I tried the below:

- deleting the logs directory manually and re-running kafka/zookeeper, however the same error still occurs at a later point in time.
- changing the logs directory from the server configuration to nest elsewhere and not in the */tmp*; did not resolve the issue.

This error happens many times on a daily basis, independently of the log retention configuration. The server configuration properties (*server.properties*) are the default ones:

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Comment: Can you share your configuration (`server.properties`) ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Of course, I included them in the description above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your `log.dirs` which is currently set to `tmp/kafka-logs`. This might cause some troubles when your machine turns off as the content of `tmp/` will be purged.

---

Try to change the path to a permanent location instead of `tmp/`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I've noted in the issue description, I tried using a directrory other than /tmp, e.g. inside my home dir, but the issue persists.

Comment: @IoannisAntoniadis I see but I would say that after applying this fix, you also need to wipe your older topics as they are currently in a corrupted state. At least this is my guess.